# ¿Cómo recibir una fecha y utilizarla para update PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Se me está presentando un problema con PHP, el cual busco traer de *SQL* una fecha, la cual juega como vencimiento y almacenarla en una variable, posterior a ello, validar si esa fecha es mayor o menor para poder ejecutar un `update` incrementando **1 o 2 meses** con la variable `$meses`.

```
$meses = $_POST['meses'];

$sql= "SELECT fecha_ven FROM usuario WHERE user='$user'";
$vencimiento = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($meses2 == 1){
    $fecha = strtotime( '+1 month' , strtotime( $vencimiento ));
    $fecha = date( "Y-m-d (H:i:s)" , $fecha);
}
elseif ($meses2 == 2){
    $fecha = strtotime ( '+2 month' , strtotime ( $vencimiento ) ) ;
    $fecha = date( "Y-m-d (H:i:s)" , $fecha);
}
$consulta = "SELECT creditos FROM admins WHERE user='".$_SESSION["user"]."'";
$resultado2 = $mysqli->query($consulta);

if ($resultado2 >= $meses){
    if ($vencimiento >= $fecha){        
        $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET pass='$pass', nombre='$nombre',    fecha_ven='$nuevafecha2' WHERE user= '$user'";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $restar_propietario = "UPDATE admins SET creditos = creditos - $meses WHERE user ='".$_SESSION["user"]."'";
        $restado = $mysqli->query($restar_propietario);
    }
    else{
        $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET pass='$pass', nombre='$nombre', fecha_ven='$nuevafecha', status='$status'  WHERE user= '$user'";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $restar_propietario = "UPDATE admins SET creditos = creditos - $meses WHERE user ='".$_SESSION["user"]."'";
        $restado = $mysqli->query($restar_propietario);
    }
}
```

La intención es que si la fecha de vencimiento es `>=` a la fecha actual, incremente `1` mes a la misma fecha de vencimiento, y en caso de que sea menor, lo que requiero es que le asigne `1` mes a partir del día de **hoy**, día del `update`.

Answer (score 2):

a ver si te sirve esto que use hace poco:

```
$timeActual= time();   // Obtenemos el timestamp del momento actual
$timeVencimiento = strtotime($fechaConsultaSQL); // Obtenemos timestamp de la fecha de vencimiento

// Calculamos el número de segundos que tienen esos 30 días
$segundos = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;

// Condición: Si la diferencia entre la fecha de vencimiento y la fecha actual es menor de 30 días
if( $timeVencimiento-$timeActual < $segundos) { codigo si es menor a 30}else {codigo si es mayor}
```

Espero sirva, un abrazo!